# Change z-index of stacked divs when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs with position:fixed, top:0, left: 0 and 100% in height and width on top of each other.

I'm trying to be able to scroll through the divs by changing the z-index, as I scroll. I have no idea how to achieve this.

In other words, trying to create a scrollable page without having to visually scroll vertically or horizontally. Instead staying on the same spot and reveal the content by changing z-index, if that makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Serina, your question is far too broad to be solvable on stack overflow. Fortunately there should be a lot of examples of sites that do what you're trying to do, and there are probobly a lot of libraries as well. Hope you find something that can give you a start.

Comment: So, are you wanting like a 3d zoom-in effect as you scoll? Or are you wanting elements to just pop into existance? Either way, z-index is probably not what you want - z-index just lays out how elements are ordered relative to each other, but won't hide/show them, nor provide any 3d effects.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I've seen a few sites using it and I think they achieve it with javascript, but I have no knowledge of it so it's difficult to know what I'm looking for. I'll try again though.

It's hard to describe so I hope linking a site as example is okay. This site is doing it: https://bjoernwieland.com/ He has 5 sections which changes z-index when scrolling. The sections are all stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as you asked:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let active = 0,
  delayTimer = null;

addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  // If we just scrolled, don't do anything
  if (delayTimer !== null) return;

  // Apply the section change
  const upwards = e.deltaY < 0;

  if ((upwards && active > 0) || (!upwards && active < sections.length - 1)) {
    // Make the current one go one level below
    const previous = sections[active];
    previous.classList.add('previous');
    previous.classList.remove('active');
    // In 500ms, the animation will be over, hide it
    setTimeout(() => previous.classList.remove('previous'), 500);
    // Move the new current one to the front
    active += upwards ? -1 : 1;
    sections[active].classList.add('active');
  }

  // Prevent that from happening again during the next 500ms
  // so that we don't scroll multiple sections at once
  delayTimer = setTimeout(() => { delayTimer = null; }, 500);
});
```

```css
body { background: #222; }
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #555; color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
section:nth-child(1) { background: #6A46F2; }
section:nth-child(2) { background: #F28B77; }
section:nth-child(3) { background: #A1BA44; }
section:nth-child(4) { background: #52bc93; }

section.previous, section.active {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}
section.active {
  z-index: 2;
  animation: fadeIn .4s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; transform: scale(.6); }
  to { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<section class="active"><h1>Section A</h1><p>Some content A</p></section>
<section><h1>Section B</h1><p>Some content B</p></section>
<section><h1>Section C</h1><p>Some content C</p></section>
<section><h1>Section D</h1><p>Some content D</p></section>
```

Comment: I gave the sections a class because I'm trying to add some entrance animations to the sections for a more smooth transition between them and also when scrolling back. It only seem to work for section A once, possible because all sections are in the viewport already so the animations has happened before scrolling and can't repeat.

I also tried to add a div inside the sections because I'm probably going to need it for content, but that breaks the script.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've updated the example with an animation and some content. It now uses 2 classes. By default, sections are hidden. If they have the `.previous` class, they are at `z-index: 1`, and if they are active, they are at `z-index: 2`. That way, you can animate the new one in front of the previous one. But of course, that might need to be adapted depending on the animation you want